# what is the best way of using the label element in an html form?

Tags: html, forms, label

when do we wrap around both the text description & the form in put & when shall we keep the label separate from the form control?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input to be triggered when clicking on label you should wrap your input into label like this: `<label><input type="radio"> Label Text</label>`

Or you can enable this triggering by giving and id on input and take it as the for attribute on label like this: `<label for="theID">Label Text</label><input id="theID" type="radio">`.

But if you don't want triggering the input on label click only then you don't need any of these 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correctly, you want to know the difference between following-

1. label wrapped around both the text description & the form input-

```html
<label>
Male<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
</label>
```

2. Label separate from form control-

```html
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
```

Well, the functionality of both these is same. The only difference is `for` attribute which is used to define the input field to which the label is assigned.

You can use the first method only if input field and label are together in document (next to each other like in the snippets). If they are far away from each other in the document, you have to use the second method to define the input field for label. Consider following example-

```html
<label for="male">Select Male</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"> Male
```